# Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android

I have implemented Comaprable on class , and it gives me  Comparison method violates its general contract! , as there are some values which are returned as null , code is as follows

public static Comparator NameComparator
            = new Comparator() {

```
    public int compare(JSONReceiptList rName1, JSONReceiptList rName2) {
        if(rName1.retailer!=null || rName2.retailer!=null) {


            if(rName1.retailer==null||rName2.retailer==null) {

                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(rName1.retailer.retailerName==null ||rName2.retailer.retailerName==null ) {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {String Name1 = rName1.retailer.getRetailerName().toUpperCase();
                    String Name2 = rName2.retailer.getRetailerName().toUpperCase();
                    return Name1.compareTo(Name2);

                }
            }
            //ascending order

        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Yes, your comparison violates the contract. If you have `x`, `y` and `z` such that `x < z` (nothing null) but `y` has null values, so `compare(x, y)` is 0 and `compare(y, z)` is 0. Fundamentally, you need to rethink the outcome when values are null.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is a contract violation.
From [Comparator API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> It follows immediately from the contract for compare that the quotient is an equivalence relation on S, and that the imposed ordering is a total order on S.

A [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) is transitive, antisymmetric, and total.

But the order imposed by your code is not transitive. If x and y have non null values and x < y but z has has null values then :

compare(x,z) = 0. compare(y,z) = 0.
So, per transitive property, compare(x,y) should be zero but it is not the case.

One possible solution is to consider null values as the lowest ones.

```
  public int compare(JSONReceiptList rName1, JSONReceiptList rName2) {
      boolean r1IsNull = rName1.retailer==null || rName1.retailer.retailerName==null;
      boolean r2IsNull = rName2.retailer==null || rName2.retailer.retailerName==null;
      if ( r1IsNull && r2IsNull )
          return 0;
      else if ( r1IsNull  && !r2IsNull )
          return -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      else if ( !r1IsNull && r2IsNull )
          return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      else // Both are non null
      {
            String name1 = rName1.retailer.getRetailerName().toUpperCase();
            String name2 = rName2.retailer.getRetailerName().toUpperCase();
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment , i got the solution , actually null values were creating problem ,name1 and name2 when both are null